# Disable XML layout changes on preview touch (Android Studio 2.2.2)

Tags: android, android-studio, xml-layout

On the Android Studio 2.2.2, every time I barely touch or click the preview layout of an XML layout file, it does change and I will have to revert those changes. Is there a way to disable that?